# Multiple-Indexing nested matrices in APL

Tags: apl

I've looked everywhere for a function to do this but given a nested vector

```
A←(5 3 2) (3 9 1)
```

I'd like to index it with B

```
B ← 2 1
```

So that for the first item in A, the 2nd item will be returned. And for the second item for A will have 3 (the first item) returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the index function, applied with the each operator:

```
      A←(5 3 2) (3 9 1) 
      B←2 1
      B⌷¨A
3 3
```

Note that you should not confuse the index function with the quad function, which is a wider box.

Comment: Thanks Paul, your method is much simpler than what I was trying to achieve with dyadic disclose/first.

Comment: Glad it helped. I think it is considered good form on StackOverflow to  accept an answer as correct if it is helpful and in fact is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use "pick": `B⊃¨A`